# Passing an array of objects for search

Tags: c++, search

```
#include<iostream.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
class student
{ int rno;
  char name[20];
  float total;
  public:
  void In();
  void Out();
  void search(student ob[50],int,int);
  int retrno()
  { return rno;               //returns the roll no of student 
  }
};
void student::search(student ob[],int n,int srno)
{ int flag=0;
  for(int i=0;i<n;++i)
     if(ob[i].retrno()==srno)     //checking for rollno match
       { flag=1;
         cout<<"Student found";
         ob[i].Out();                 //calling Out() when match is found
       }
   if(flag==0)
   cout<<"No matching records";
}
void student::In()
{ cout<<"Enter rno:";
  cin>>rno;
  cout<<"Enter name:";
  gets(name);
  cout<<"Enter total:";
  cin>>total;
}
void student::Out()
{ cout<<"rno:";
  cout<<rno;
  cout<<"Name:";
  puts(name);
  cout<<"Total:";
  cout<<total;
}
void main()
{ student ob[50];
  int n,srno;
  cout<<"Enter no. of students:";
  cin>>n;
  for(int i=0;i<n;++i)
       ob[i].In();                    //In() is called n times
  cout<<"Enter rno to be searched:";
  cin>>srno;
  ob.search(ob,n,srno);
 }
```

On compiling I get 2 errors.

```
11: Undefined structure 'student'

52: Structure required on left side of . or .*
```

I tried to see if there's a mistake in the function prototype but it looks fine.I tired the prototype without array size and obtained same errors. I also tried initializing the class globally but got same errors (I ran out of ideas).
Please help me find what the problem is.

Comment: `ob.search(ob,n,srno);` you need to specify an index: `ob[42].search(ob,n,srno);`

Comment: Without addressing your problem, if you have any book recommending the use of `iostream.h` or `conio.h`, that book is probably horribly outdated. Mixing IOStreams and stdio is also not a good idea. Get a newer tutorial.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I tried that now.The first error persists.Since I am running a for loop inside search(),will specifying the index create problems?

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt Please bear with me.The teacher taught us all this,it is part of school syllabus and there is nothing I can do to change it.No, I cannot leave to a new school as the syllabus is the same all across the country.

Comment: @SMcCK You should overthink your class design, and consider to implement something that supports [`std::find()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find) operating on your array.

Answer (score 0):

Your `student` class represent a single student, I think it's better for the search function not to be a member of it, considering that you pass to it an array of student too:

```
void search(student ob[], int n, int srno)
{
    // ... keep your implementation
}
```

Then you can call that with:

```
search(ob,n,srno);
```

It would be even better to separate the output part and make the search function only return an index or a pointer to the element found (or not).

I agree with Ulrich Eckhardt about the included libraries.

I'd add that you should check somehow what the users input and I'd like to remember that's more correct to use:

```
int main() {
    // ... stuff...
    return 0;
}
```